# How to change screen in Python if Screen Manager is defined in kivy file?

Tags: python, kivy

My program takes input in one screen and then goes and displays it in to another. I want to make a condition that the screen only changes when the value is digit greater than 0.
My screen manager is defined in kivy file.
My question is how to use this "root.manager.current = "SecondScreen"" command in my condition. I don't know how to reference it.
Or maybe there is a way to make condition in .kv file?

main.py

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
    from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
    from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty

    global var
    global pp
    pp = '0'
    class FirstScreen(Screen):
        global pp
        ppp = StringProperty('')
        def g(self, text):
            global pp
            if text.isdigit() and int(text) > 0:
                pp = text
```

my test.kv file

```
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    FirstScreen:
        id: screen1
        name: "FirstScreen"
        manager: screen_manager
    SecondScreen:
        id: screen2
        name: "SecondScreen"
        manager: screen_manager
<FirstScreen>:
    text_input: text_input
    FloatLayout:
        id: fl1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1
            Rectangle:
                # self here refers to the widget i.e BoxLayout
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        TextInput:
            id: text_input
            text: root.ppp
            multiline: False
            size_hint_x: .4
            size_hint_y: .1
            pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'y': .20}
        Button:
            background_color: 0.2, 0.7, 1, 1,
            font_size: root.width / 15
            id: btn1
            text: "Next"
            on_press:
                root.g(text_input.text)
                root.manager.current = 'SecondScreen'
            size_hint_x: .4
            size_hint_y: .1
            pos_hint: {'x': .5, 'y': .20}
<SecondScreen>:
    on_enter: root.f()
    FloatLayout:
        id: fl2
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1
            Rectangle:
                # self here refers to the widget i.e BoxLayout
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Label:
            color: 0.2, 0.7, 1, 1,
            font_size: 15
            id: lb1
            text: root.idf
            size_hint_y: .2
            pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'y': .8}
```

Answer (score 9):

The method in kvlang:

```
app.root.current = 'screen_name_you_want_to_switch_to'
```

Can be done in python by using self.parent in your screen class:

```
self.parent.current = 'screen_name_you_want_to_switch_to'
```

self.parent refers to the parent object (screenmanager) of the self object (screen)

Example showing both is shown below, first a sidenote on your textinput: I *think* you may be able to access the value by using `self.ids['text_input'].text` directly, you could try it.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0') 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen

kvlang = '''
<ScreenManagement>:
    ScreenOne:
    ScreenTwo:

<ScreenOne>:
    name: 'First'
    id: screen1
    Button:
        text: 'screen 1, press me to switch to screen 2, defined in python'
        on_press: root.switch()

<ScreenTwo>:
    name: 'Second'
    id: screen2
    Button:
        text: 'screen 2, press me to switch to screen 1, defined in kvlang'
        on_press: app.root.current = 'First'
'''

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    def switch(self):
        #here you can insert any python logic you like 
        self.parent.current = 'Second'

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kvlang)
        return ScreenManagement()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to swap screens within the python file. Firstly define the screen manager simply as this with no properties or children (adding the screen will be done in python)

```
<ScreenManager>:
```

Add a ScreenManager class to the python file along with classes for FirstScreen and SecondScreen. Give ScreenManager() methods to swap in FirstScreen and SecondScreen

```
class ScreenManager(widget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.show_FirstScreen()

    def show_FirstScreen(self):
        firstscreen = FirstScreen()
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(firstscreen)

    def show_SecondScreen(self):
        secondscreen = SecondScreen()
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(secondscreen)
```

Then add a method which is called by an on_press button event to execute some logic before showing a different screen, e.g.

```
    def handle_button(self):
        if <some logic>:
            self.show_SecondScreen()
```

The button presses within the .kv file will have to reach up to the ScreenManager class to get to the handle_button method, something like root.parent.handle_button, depending on the depth of the structure